# jQuery amazing easing

Tags: jquery, hide, slide, easing

How to achieve something like there:

http://ofertymieszkan.pl/

(click "DALEJ" green button in the middle and then optinally "podstawowej wyszukiwarce" below "WYSZUKAJ" button)

Element fades in and then elegantly disappears.

Any demos/ideas etc.?

Comment: That site uses jQuery. You could just look through their JavaScript code...

Comment: @Matt Ball I know but the file is minimized :(

Comment: Give it a try. If you don't know jQuery, run through some tutorials. If you get stuck on something specific, ask a question.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance, it's basically just using `animate()` changing the `left` and `opacity` values. Very roughly, this is what their code does:

```
$('#estate_search_submit').click(function ()
{
    $('#first-step').animate({left: '-=250', opacity: 0});
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7yTK3/2/

That gets the first step to slide away. I'll let you figure out how to get the second step to slide in.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery `animate()`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
I figure it's simultaneously animating `left` and `opacity`.

Here's a quick example I brewed for you: http://jsfiddle.net/PTyue/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com/) offers this kind of capability and a variety of easing options for its [show](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/) and [hide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/hide/) functions.

If you dig into the code for the site you reference, they are using jQuery and jQuery UI (it's minified and combined into a file called app.js).

Answer (score 0):

It is jQuery. Effects are [fade](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fade) and [slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide). Use can use main effect animate() and configure you how you want

(links are from jQuery UI documentation)